# Make a personal stats page available

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, statistics, personal-statistics

I would really enjoy having a stats page available in my profile showing me for which tags I have given how many answers, and how much reputation I got for all those answers.

I can do it somewhat with the "Stats" on the main page when I selected a tag - but that's not collecting together all my own personal stats, it shows everyone for that tag. I'd like to see it from the other side - show me all **MY** tags I've provided answers for, with number of answers provided and amount of reputation earned for those answers.

Marc

Comment: `status-completed` as per the December 16th [what do the numbers next to the tagnames mean in my profile?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72482/what-do-the-numbers-next-to-the-tagnames-mean-in-my-profile) (implemented [December 10th](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38860/how-can-i-see-how-many-upvotes-and-downvotes-i-have-per-tag/71884#71884) or earlier), which seems to be what you're asking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is now available on your user page in the tags section:

[image: tag scores]

Comment: Thanks to the Stack team for this!!