# How can I see how many upvotes and downvotes I have per tag?

Tags: support, tags, voting, tag-badges

Is there any way for me to see how many upvotes and downvotes I have in a given tag? I am working toward having two tag badges and would like to know how far from my aim I am.

Comment: See also here for a stackql query: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26560/stackql-query-to-determine-your-own-tag-badge-progress

Comment: @Ether: It's only not updated daily.. It's currently still hosting the October 2009 data. Would otherwise indeed have been great.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can check the [user stats page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/topusers) for that tag if you are in the Top 20. The light grey number is how many upvotes.

Remember the scope you are looking at. One column is just the upvotes for past 30 days, the other is all time.

If you aren't on that page, I don't believe there is one.

Comment: Guess what, for django I am :-) Thanks a lot. Now, bring my that python ;-)

Comment: Yep, I am on the list for Python too ;-) Now, I just need to move myself from the 30 day list, to the all time list ;)

Comment: I shows a number of upvotes for *Answers* and a number for *Questions*, are the total of both towards receiving the badge or just the total of answers?

Answer (score 12):

Your user page now shows your score per tag, under the tags section. Mouse over the number to get a detailed breakdown.

Answer (score 7):

I've also [posted a report online here](http://hewgill.com/~greg/stackoverflow/stack_overflow/users/) that shows a number of stats, including upvotes and downvotes, for each user and tag. Currently I've only run that query for users with over 20k reputation, so unfortunately it doesn't show your account. But hopefully this will be useful for others. :)

Comment: Is it just me, or is this link broken?

Comment: @Chris: Fixed now, thanks. Since I originally posted that link, I've added stats for all the other sites in the data dump too, which changed the link.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a greasemonkey script that will fetch your tag stats for you:

[I'm not appearing in the all-time list for java, is this a bug?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20896/im-not-appearing-in-the-all-time-list-for-java-is-this-a-bug/21623#21623)