# How can I find which tags I am strongest in?

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I see how many upvotes and downvotes I have per tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38860/how-can-i-see-how-many-upvotes-and-downvotes-i-have-per-tag)

I've been on SO for quite a while now and I'm just wondering which tags are my strong points. Is there a quick way (in my profile or something) that can show me? If not, this would be a cool feature.

Being able to split it up by question/answer would be nice too. For instance, I ask a lot of questions in ASP.Net but I answer many in PHP or something.

Comment: The tags on your profile page are displayed in order starting at the top left and going down each column.

Comment: @ChrisF but not by number of upvotes, are they? I think it's sorted by number of *answers*.

Comment: @Pekka - You're right. I don't know why I thought it was sorted by upvotes.

Comment: @ChrisF it would be the natural way, I don't know why they decided to use a different sorting order here. Counting upvotes is probably more expensive than counting answers

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this query](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/137/how-many-upvotes-do-i-have-towards-tag-specialist-badges) on SEDE.