# What is the number to the left of a tag in my profile?

Tags: support, tags, profile-page

What does the number to the left of a tag listed in my profile represent?

[image: number next to tag in profile]

Comment: Hover over the number. (:

Comment: thank you for answering... but damn you for helping me realize my inferiority in the shadow of jon skeet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means you have a **sum** of 12 votes for non community-wiki answers on questions tagged `javascript`

For example:

- You may have been upvoted 14 times and downvoted twice.
- You may have another 100 votes on a popular wiki answer on a question tagged javascript ... this is ignored from the calculation

Answer (score 0):

I hovered over the number, and it still took me a few moments to realize what the tooltip was saying.  The wording could be better. I believe it was saying:

```
You answered x questions in this tag, and received total rep of y from those answers.
```

[image]

Comment: Note the difference: points form question you _asked_ and questions you _answered_ are listed separately.

Comment: Not completely true: gained rep is not listed, but the total number of votes you received is, like Mr Waffles explains.