# How can I get my reputation and votes per tag?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, reputation, tags

For example ,

java -> (4) correct answer, (+20) up vote , (-5) down vote , (250) reputation

Comment: `status-completed` as per the December 16th [what do the numbers next to the tagnames mean in my profile?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72482/what-do-the-numbers-next-to-the-tagnames-mean-in-my-profile) (implemented [December 10th](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38860/how-can-i-see-how-many-upvotes-and-downvotes-i-have-per-tag/71884#71884) or earlier), which seems to be what you're asking for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is now available on your user page in the tags section:

[image: tag scores]

Answer (score 2):

I had a go at creating a query for this on data explorer.

It displays the information you want however you need to remember that the total reputation won't add up to your current reputation as you can assign multiple tags to one question.

So a question tagged `sql-server` & `sql-server-2005` will only have 1 vote for the entire answer but will be duplicated in the results in data explorer as the tags are displayed separately.

You can [look at the query here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/756/tag-information).

Comment: Nice. That looks far better than my [temporary tables method](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/17073/breakdown-reputation-vote-history-by-tag) that times out when I run it

Comment: And see the December 16th [what do the numbers next to the tagnames mean in my profile?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72482/what-do-the-numbers-next-to-the-tagnames-mean-in-my-profile) which seems to cover this?

Comment: @Arjan - are you checking up on all my answers? ;-)