# Provide statistics about tags I'm good at

Tags: support, tags, statistics, personal-statistics

It would be nice to see the topics I'm good at, i.e. the top tags that gained me some reputation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get my reputation and votes per tag?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73307/how-can-i-get-my-reputation-and-votes-per-tag)

Comment: @Arjan: That doesn't directly indicate productivity (ie reputation per question/answer).

Comment: (@Andrew, this feature request was about tags, not questions, right? But meanwhile this has been tagged `support`, so no `status-completed` either. I've removed my comments to clean up.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

At the bottom of the [user profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/326370) (which you can access by clicking anywhere your name appears as a link, like in top bar), you can find the (non-[CW](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)) votes earned per tag. As usual: hover the numbers to see a tooltip with details.

[image]

---

On top of every tag-specific page, like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php you can find a link to [*top users*](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/topusers).

[image]

---

This should lead you to an overview of top users and you should be able to compare your position to others.