# Digit next to tags on profile page under "Tags"

Tags: support, tags, profile-page

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the number to the left of a tag in my profile?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72482/what-is-the-number-to-the-left-of-a-tag-in-my-profile)

On my Stack Overflow account profile, under "Tags", all the tags I've mentioned in my questions are listed. To the left of each tag is a digit in a grey box. Presently, all are 0. What do these digits represent? It can't be number of upvotes on the questions or answers 'cause I do have got votes on all the questions and answers.

Comment: I've never noticed before how much the word "digit" looks like "dig-it" without a space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These numbers show how many points on **answers** you've got. From a random tag on myh profile, which shows "407":

> Asked 5 non-wiki questions with a total score of 9. 
>   Answered 290 non-wiki questions with a total score of 407."

So it's not the questions that count, otherwise it should be 416 in my case.

Comment: Ok. But I have votes on my answers as well!?

Comment: what does the titel say?  And might it be cache?

Comment: "Answered 1 non-wiki questions with a total score of 0." But when I navigate to the answer, I've obviously gained one vote. Possibly, it hasn't updated the number, since I got the vote earlier today. But SO usually is quite fast at detecting various actions on the site.

Comment: I'd say you want to give the various backgroundthingys some time to update.

Comment: Several hours?!

Comment: Why not? Flair has a 24 hour cache, why would it be hard to believe something like this has a longish cache?

Comment: It's not hard to believe. I just have the experience of SO to give me rep immediately when I receive votes and reward badges as soon as I complete "badge requirements". Thought it was gonna be equally as fast in this matter.